# Firebase for Cordova app - Failed to fetch APNS token

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, firebase, apple-push-notifications

I am trying to make Firebase push notifications work on an iOS device on a Cordova app using [this plugin](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase), but I am getting problem after problem. I don't even know where to start, so let me just show you my console log when I load the app.

```
MyApp[754:298085] Starting Firebase plugin
MyApp[754:298085] [CDVTimer][firebaseplugin] 0.200033ms
MyApp[754:298085] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 73.943019ms
MyApp[754:298119] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
MyApp[754] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
MyApp[754:298117] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3404000 started
MyApp[754:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3404000 started
MyApp[754:298117] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see some link here)
MyApp[754:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled (see some link here)
MyApp[754:298085] Firebase Crash Reporting: Successfully enabled
 <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch APNS token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=1001 "(null)"
 <FIRMessaging/INFO> FIRMessaging library version 1.2.0
MyApp[754:298118] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000018] Already sending logs.
MyApp[754] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000018] Already sending logs.
MyApp[754:298118] libMobileGestalt MobileGestaltSupport.m:153: pid 754 (MyApp) does not have sandbox access for frZQaeyWLUvLjeuEK43hmg and IS NOT appropriately entitled
MyApp[754:298118] libMobileGestalt MobileGestalt.c:550: no access to InverseDeviceID (see <rdar://problem/11744455>)
MyApp[754:298124] <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at some link here
MyApp[754:] <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> The AdSupport Framework is not currently linked. Some features will not function properly. Learn more at some link here
MyApp[754:298119] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
MyApp[754:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
MyApp[754:298085] Resetting plugins due to page load.
MyApp[754:298119] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
MyApp[754] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
MyApp[754:298085] Connected to FCM.
MyApp[754:298085] InstanceID token: eD1pW3DsaUA:APA91bGSKxvd6VRf-3O1_AgQcdCL3ZLERsWDShsFy8LE6MlNLTgFl-sYH9EzvPZJn9JH-oRjvhwQrwp-h6YukJ86IQP0Q4iLnOf4GwoPgR5dV1ozLX1Fnc7bpJDMOtukAriLT8NZSAVl
MyApp[754:298132] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
2017-05-19 16:05:39.389 MyApp[754] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
MyApp[754:298085] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/0A7C5C10-135D-4E34-A2BC-D64528786544/MyApp.app/www/index.html
MyApp[754:298085] THREAD WARNING: ['FirebasePlugin'] took '4102.684082' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

as you can see from all this bullsh** I am getting a FCM token, but not an APNS. I think I have uploaded every kind of needed certificate, and even a .p8 certificate in the Firebase Settings for APNS Auth Key.

I also tried to send a test notification from the Firebase Notification console using the provided push token from the debug console, but nothing arrives on the device, when in foreground or in background. I am debugging both the javascript and the native code to see that.

What else can I do, I don't even know how to check if all my certificates are ok or if I am missing something, please help.

EDIT: I have turned on the Push Notifications under Capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what the problem was, but I tried with another plugin, [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm), and after I made sure the application had permission to receive pushes, and everything else on the project was configured fine, I started receiving pushes.

Answer (score 0):

Turn on the push notifications under the project targets > capabilities.
It worked for me.

Comment: Push notification, Background mode (Remote notification), Keychain sharing must be enabled.
Then try to remove FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabledflag in Config.plist as reported here: [https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/ios-migrate-fcm)

Comment: I enabled all those, and selected Push notifications in the Background mode, also tried with and without FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled, still nothing. I am even testing from the Firebase console, sending a push to a single device, or to the app